# KDB projection with multiple variables

Tags: kdb

I have a function on KDB server as `test[date;sym;starttime;endtime]` and I want to run this function for list of symbol with specific date, starttime and endtime. for eg `Test[2014.07.02,IBM,09:30:00,"11:00:25.325"]` is one such row of the list which i want to pass to the "Test" function. I understand the projection function in KDB for eg each right/left (x f/: y) but how to pass a list of specific values for all the input arguments. Please see below for the input list

```
  Date     Symbol   Starttime   Endtime

2014.07.02  IBM     09:30:45    15:59:59.2

2014.07.03  AAPL    09:40:50    13:52:19.125
```

I will appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks,

Comment: For the sake of information, the "Test" Function returns a list of values..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my understanding of your doubt:

You have a list of inputs as L:(inputs1;inputs2;...) , where inputs1 is a list of (date;symbol;starttime;endtime) and you want to apply 'test' function on each  input list in 'L'.

For this, KDB provide 'dot' operator.

Ex:

```
    q) f:{[a;b;c]  a+b+c}
    q) f . (1 2 3)
    q) 6
```

For list of inputs:

```
    q) f ./: ((1 2 3);(4 5 6))
    q) 6  15
```

In your case, it would be like:

```
    q)test ./:L
```

Reference: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for the help.I am not sure why the dot operator is not working. I tried running the below code: test ./:(2014.07.02 `IBM 09:30:00 15:59:59.2) but the server sent me an error as : "An error occurred during execution of the query.
The server sent the response:IBM ". However, when i ran the same input in the format as test[2014.07.02;`IBM;09:30:00; 15:59:59.2]..it ran fine..Could the dot operator may not be working because the test function returns a list.. Thanks a lot again for the help..

Comment: What happens when you try: ``test ./:enlist(2014.07.02;`IBM;09:30:00;15:59:59)`` - the semi-colons are needed when declaring a mixed type list.

Comment: You are missing 2 things which is also mentioned by MdSalih. First, use enlist to make your input as list of list. Second, use semicolon between elements of mixed list.

Comment: Thanks MDsalih, Rahul.

Comment: Thanks MDsalih, Rahul. test./:enlist(2014.07.02;`IBM ;09:30:00;15:59:59.2) worked perfectly fine. However, thats only one element of the list..Lets say i have one more element 2014.07.03;AAPL;09:40:50;13:52:19.125 and i want to run both the elements together..for eg something like this: test./:enlist((2014.07.02;`IBM;09:30:00;15:59:59.2);(2014.07.02;`AAPL;09:30:00;15:59:59.2))..how should i go about it..Thanks a lot for the help. I really appreciate it...

Comment: you use 'enlist' to convert single item to a list. Now  you have two items in a list which means it is already a list of lists. So no need to use enlist now. Use: test./:((2014.07.02;IBM;09:30:00;15:59:59.2);(2014.07.02;`AAPL;09:30:00;1‌​5:59:59.2))